# How to add dynamic to static classes in a link_to in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Say I have some HAML and I want to have a `link_to` with a bootstrap `btn` class that resolves to

```
class: `btn btn-grouped btn-close`
```

But I also want to add a conditional to add class `hidden` if some status is true?

So the classes maybe be this:

```
btn btn-grouped btn-close disabled
```

But they also maybe be this:

```
btn btn-grouped btn-close
```

I tried doing two `class:` declarations. That does not seem to work for me.

My goal is to do with this without having an extra space on the end of the class list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no reason to care about extra space in HTML classnames. If it annoys, you could define a helper:

```
def hidden_classname(status)
  return 'hidden' if status
end
```

Then invoke method passing needed `status` parameter in view:

```
%div{ class: "#{['btn', 'btn-grouped', 'btn-close', hidden_classname(status)].compact.join(' ')}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I  understand you right, next snippet may help you::

```
%div{:class => "num_seat passenger_seat #{'hidden' if !f.object.available_for_seat?}" }
```

Comment: won't that add an extra space to the end of the class list? There should be a way without adding an extra space right?

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like this:

```
class: "btn btn-grouped btn-close #{button_visibility}"
```

Then add `button_visibility` to your helper.

```
def button_visibility 
  if some_status == true
    "hidden"
  else
    "disabled"
  end
end
```

Comment: won't that add an extra space to the end of the class list if `button_visibility` is false? There should be a way without adding an extra space right?

Comment: just return `''` if you're worried about that, in my example you're either returning 'hidden' or 'disabled'